# Intellij Run short cut not working on mac

Tags: intellij-idea, shortcut

I use Mac OS X 10.5+ Keymap and tried to run my program with control + R but i only see Run button on menu turn blue once without running program. I check and there is no conflict with this shortcut. What can be the problem?

Comment: Looks like if i use control+ R in my program file, it will not work. But if i change focus to project viewer tab, it will work

Answer (score 0):

Activating a button means that the button is available.